# TypeError: data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, node-fetch

Im really stuck on this figuring out what did I miss, Im not that expert about javascript, if someone can please tell me what I did wrong, I really appreciate.

I have a working code:

```
if (value_ == "group") {
  fetch("http://localhost/someapi"+value_).then(r => { return r.json()})
  .then(json => {
      var data =  `{ "group" : [{"name":"foo","tag":"bar"},{"name":"bool","tag":"lean"}] }`;
      var data = JSON.parse(data); 
      var groupName = data.group.map(current => current.name);
      var groupTag = data.group.map(current => current.tag);
      console.log(data);         
      console.log(`json: ${data.group[0].name}`);
    });
}
```

the code above will work and get every data I wanted, but the json is from the:

```
var data =  `{ "group" : [{"name":"foo","tag":"bar"},{"name":"bool","tag":"lean"}] }`;
```

then I tried to get the json from the URL which return the same value as the var data above. But it doesn' work.

which I did change var `data = JSON.parse(data);` into `data = JSON.parse(json)`

and delete "var data =  `{ "group" : [{"name":"foo","tag":"bar"},{"name":"bool","tag":"lean"}] }`;"

And it does give an error: `(node:10868) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

I also tried this code:

```
  fetch("http://localhost/someapi"+value_).then(r => { return r.json()})
  .then(json => {
      parseJSON(JSON.stringify(json));
      function parseJSON(str){
        var data = JSON.parse(str); 
        var groupName = data.group.map(current => current.name);
        var groupTag = data.group.map(current => current.tag);
        console.log(data);         
        console.log(`json: ${data.group[0].name}`);
      }

    });
}
```

this give me error: `(node:12668) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

Thanks and pardon my english.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're doing `JSON.stringify` and then immediately doing `JSON.parse` on the results? why not just say `var data = json;`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I did use that to make my other code work, but it is different environment of code. In case in my other code if I straight use `var data = json;` it will give me `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

 I'm not that expert like I said, so Im just figguring out whats happening here and learn to fix it.

Comment: Your parse method works fine when you pass the `data` variable. I expect the problem is in the content of the `json` variable. Did you log its content?

Comment: the content of the json on my api url is exactly same like in the `var = data` if thats what you're asking for.

Comment: to figure out what's going on with your fetch results, you'll probably want to take a look at the actual text being sent in response to your fetch. Either in the developer tools network pane, or by temporarily changing the `r.json()` to `r.text()` and then `console.log` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to execute JSON.parse manually because the content of `json` variable in the third line of your example is already an object.

Try this:

```
fetch("http://localhost/someapi"+value_)
.then(r => r.json())
.then(json => {
  var groupName = json.group.map(current => current.name);
  var groupTag = json.group.map(current => current.tag);
  console.log('groupName', groupName);         
  console.log('groupTag', groupTag);         
});
```

Comment: just need to put the `var data = json;` and it is work now..
so basically, I dont need to use a parse manually if its direcly from the `fetch("url").then(r=>{ return response.json()}).then json => { .... }` ?

Comment: I wrote almost the same in my answer. You don't need additional `data` variable. Just use `json` variable then you receive in `then` callback.

Comment: The JSON string from the response is parsed by `.then(r=>{ return response.json()})`. Also, you can drop redundant brackets and `return` statement there. Just `.then(r => r.json())` will be enough.

Comment: Yea, but before it was `data.group.map` on your code before. But doesn't matter anymore.

I get the point from what you explained. Thanks again !

Comment: You're right. I noticed the error only after submitting my answer.

Comment: If everything works and you question if solved I'd appreciate if you mark my answer as the best answer.